# OpenCart: Adding payment specific order total

Tags: php, opencart, payment

I'm developing a custom payment module for OpenCart. For this, i want a specific order total, but i'm unsure how to make a order total count only for this payment option.

So far i've laid out the basic file structures for a payment module, and i can choose it on checkout. I have also added my own order total to catalog/model/total

I'm guessing that i need some logic in the getMethod of catalog/model/payment/my_payment_module

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to add an order total just for specific payment option and just for a simple reason: **order totals are calculated much sooner than user picks his payment option** - e.g. order totals are calculated already in shopping cart overview and then again in the last (confirm) step of checkout. But it should be possible to programmatically add and calculate another order total after choosing Your payment option so that it will appear only on the confirm order page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself.

I added a new Order Total class. Inside it i checked for the correct payment method in the session before returning anything.

All the totals will update when the payment method is changed, so this works fine.